# Configure Kubernetes nginx for an external access

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, lagom

I'm still new to Kubernetes and Lagom.

I need to invoke my Lagom microservice from an external server. To do that, I think that I need to expose my nginx-ingress for an external access, but I don't know how. Should I configure an "externalIPs"?

```
{
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "kind": "Service",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "nginx-ingress"
  },
  "spec": {
    "type": "LoadBalancer",
    "ports": [
      {
        "port": 80,
        "name": "http",
        "targetPort": 8080
      },
      {
        "port": 443,
        "name": "https"
      }
    ],
    "externalIPs": [
      "192.168.1.120"
    ],
    "selector": {
      "k8s-app": "nginx-ingress-lb"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No.. If you use `"type": "LoadBalancer"`, external IP will be configured automatically

Comment: I got two IP one for http "http://192.168.99.100:30370" and another one for https "https://192.168.99.100:30023". I can only invoke that IP from the local server that contains Kubernetes, But I can't do that from another server. Do you have any explanation? Please.

Comment: Where are you running kubernetes? GKE/AWS/AZURE?

Comment: No, I configured Kubernetes via Minikube on my private server

Comment: And from where you want to access this service? from your local? Or remote?

Comment: From another server (not the same network), So from Remote. For Example, I have an Android app that should consume service already deployed on Kubernetes. So I need to expose that IP for this Android App

Comment: Do you have access to your local server from that remote server?

Comment: Yes, I have access to the IP address of that server

Comment: `ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -L 30370:0.0.0.0:30370` try this

Comment: Ok I will try this, let you know. Thank you :)

Comment: Try following my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Minikube creates a network for itself and the VM. You need to externally expose your service.

**From Op's comment:** You get port `30370` for your Service. You need to expose this port.

```
ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -L \*:30370:0.0.0.0:30370
```

Comment: Hello :), I tried your solution and it is work. But, if I exit the ssh connection, I could never reach services. It would be better if I can route the minikube IP on. I tried this command "sudo route -n add 10.0.0.0/24 $(minikube ip)" but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Did you try ngrok?

Comment: Sorry for late. Yes I've tried it and it is work. With ngrok, I can invoke my service from any other device. Thank you :) PS: I did some other research and I understand that I can redirect to my minikube ip  by using Apache or Nginx.

Comment: also, to run this `ssh` in background, add `&` at the end of this command. This will run this port forwarding in background. And, if this solution works, please approve it and upvote so that future readers can take it as a solution. @Imen

Comment: Done :) Thank you again ;) @aerokite

Answer (score 1):

In Minikube, you would use the `kubectl expose` command to expose the service for external access per https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/hello-minikube/#create-a-service. Minikube is not used in production.

In production, you have three ways to create the nginx ingress service using kubernetes per https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services---service-types and expose it for external access:

1. `LoadBalancer` service type which sets the `ExternalIP` automatically. This is used when there is an external non-k8s, cloud-provider's load-balancer like CGE, AWS or Azure, and this external load-balancer would provide the `ExternalIP` for the nginx ingress service.
2. `ExternalIPs` per https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips.
3. `NodePort`. In this approach, the service can be accessed from outside the cluster using `NodeIP:NodePort/url/of/the/service`.

Along with the nginx ingress controller, you'll need an ingress resource too. Refer https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/tree/master/examples/complete-example for examples.

Comment: Hello @Vikram, thank you for your response, it is very helpful to understand how to expose service for an external access. But this solution doesn't resolve the problem because it only exposes the service for my minikube VM and I need to add some network configuration (route) to redirect the request from my server to my minikube VM. You can check the other response.

Comment: @Imen Upvote my answer if you think it is useful! Yes, network configuration (route) to redirect requests from the server to the minikube VM is needed.