# map local ip to external/host IP... IP forwarding?

Tags: macos, solr, kubernetes, portforwarding, minikube

I am running solr inside minikube for a POC. I am trying to figure out how to access the solr inside the minikube. As per my knowledge I cant access solr using my host IP, it is only accessible using the minikube IP - 192.168.99.100:8983/solr. My objective is to hit the solr server when accessing it from a remote box.

One of my team mates suggested that I can maybe use something that will forward incoming request to a local IP.

Any suggestions??

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minikube networking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48711704/minikube-networking)

Comment: You can simply check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48691246/configure-kubernetes-nginx-for-an-external-access/48693345#comment84467002_48693345

Answer (score 2):

First you need to get URL of your Service for solr.

```
$ minikube service <service-name> --url
http://192.168.99.100:30000
```

Here, `30000` is your solr Service NodePort.

Now you need to create SSH tunnel.

For that try this

```
$ ssh -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) -L \*:30000:0.0.0.0:30000
```

> Note: To keep SSH tunneling in Background, add `&` at the end of `(ssh -i .....) &`

Now you can access this solr Service using your Host IP address

Answer (score 1):

You would need to expose the solr service using the `kubectl expose` command for external access.

There are four ways to expose a service for external access in k8s:

1. `LoadBalancer` service type which sets the ExternalIP automatically. This is used when there is an external non-k8s, cloud-provider's load-balancer like CGE, AWS or Azure, and this external load-balancer would provide the ExternalIP for the nginx ingress service per https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services---service-types.
2. `ExternalIPs` per https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips.
3. `NodePort`: In this approach, the service can be hit from outside the cluster using `NodeIP:NodePort/url/of/the/service`.
4. `Ingress`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/